# can not download VSCode from China Azure site in my geographic area

Tags: visual-studio-code, download

Due to internet regulation in my residential area, I can not download VSCode  from China Azure site
(https://vscode.cdn.azure.cn/stable/0ba0ca52957102ca3527cf479571617f0de6ed50/VSCodeSetup-x64-1.43.2.exe)

VSCode official site coerced the above link to be redirected to me , I have no other choices for download point of the installer.

Does anyone kindly provide me a alternative link of other Azure region( Germany West Central etc.) to download the newest version of VSCode? 
Thank you for any clues.

Mazza Chen

Comment: Have you considered using a vpn ?

Comment: Ja, that's a good idea , Would you have any recommended VPN Server/Client combination?

Comment: theres a few but trusted such as nord vpn or express vpn